# NET8 MAUI set SecureStorage in Windows raises an error is empty

Tags: c#, maui

I'm creating a `NET8` `MAUI` app and using `SecureStorage` to save the user's username. In Android, the function is working. I call the API to authenticate the user and as response, I get the *UserId* and *UserName*. Sometimes, the *UserId* is empty.

[image]

When I save the empty *UserId* with this code in Windows (working for Android)

```
await SecureStorage.Default.SetAsync("userId", login.UserId);
await SecureStorage.Default.SetAsync("username", login.UserName);
```

the app raise this error

> System.ArgumentException: 'Value does not fall within the expected range.'

[image]

I don't expect an error if I want to save an empty string. Is this the correct behaviour for  the `SecureStorage`?

Comment: Does it break with string.Empty or "" or both and have you tried just replacing it with null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your code and reproduced the issue. And then I have check the [source code about the `SecureStorage.SetAsyc()` on the windows](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/6295ed8aba7b62fdb5014fd30f46f38f885b9dcd/src/Essentials/src/SecureStorage/SecureStorage.uwp.cs#L39).

This exception was caused by `var buffer = await provider.ProtectAsync(bytes.AsBuffer());` . This should be alimit of the windows native api. And the null will also throw an exception about value can't be null.

So the string.Empty and null are not supported for the SecureStorage in the maui on the windows platform. You can use the space(" ") instead of it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I'm going to save only real values in the `SecureStorage` for all environments.